# После создания голосового канала не могу переместить участника в канал

Tags: c#, discord

```
public async Task ChannelCreate(CommandContext ctx, [Description("Название канала")] string ChannelName)
    {
        if (ctx.Channel.Id == 927110328439930951 && ctx.Channel.ParentId == 927113749767258163)
        {
            var category = ctx.Channel.Guild.GetChannel(927113749767258163);//Получаем категорию
            var channel = await ctx.Guild.CreateVoiceChannelAsync(ChannelName, parent: category);//Делаем канал в нужной категории
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Голосовой канал с именем: " + ChannelName + " создан" + ctx.Message.Author.Mention).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await channel.PlaceMemberAsync(ctx.Member).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

При вызове  PlaceMemberAsync ничего не происходит хотя канал создается.

Comment: А где находится пользователь в момент выполнения `PlaceMemberAsync(ctx.Member)`?

Comment: Он находится просто в чате где пишут команды для бота

Comment: И как вы тогда хотите поместить его в войс? Представьте, если бы боты могли бы без ведома человека, взять, создать голосовой канал и засунуть туда любого пользователя, а потом включить запись всех его разговоров. Согласитесь, не очень хорошо, да? Как минимум по этой причине, человек сам должен зайти в любой голосовой канал, после чего его можно двигать по всем остальным.

Comment: Догадывался об этом , но просто решил не проверять. Благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Человек сам должен зайти в любой голосовой канал, после чего его можно двигать по всем остальным каналам.